# How to read a day and time on the same line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to reproduce the following entry in Python: `05 08:12:23`.

I did it as follows:

```
day, hour, minute, second = map (int, input (). Split (':'))
```

Notice how there is a space after `day` and the `split ()` I put to separate the numbers with `':'`. How would I go about reading the day on the same input? Is there a better way to do this than what I'm trying to do?

The following error ends:

```
day, hour, minute, second = map (int, input (). split (':'))
```

> ValueError: invalid literal for int () with base 10: '05 08 '

Comment: Did you consider *first* splitting the string at the space into `05` and `08:12:23` and then continue to process the two parts separately?

Comment: I didn't think about it, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have two different separators on the same line: space and colon.  You have to divide the input in two steps:

```
day, clock = input().split()
hour, minute, second = clock.split(':')
```

This leaves you with four strings, but you already know how to convert those.  :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can convert to a [`datetime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime-objects) object using the [`strptime`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.strptime) class-method with proper [format codes](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-and-strptime-format-codes):

```py
import datetime

s = "05 08:12:23"
d = datetime.datetime.strptime(s, "%d %H:%M:%S")
print(d.day, d.hour, d.minute, d.second)
```

Gives:

```
5 8 12 23
```

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to do this in one line you can write:

```
import re 
day, hour, minute, second = re.search(r"(\d\d)\s(\d\d):(\d\d):(\d\d).*", input()).group(1, 2, 3, 4)
```

What does this do?

1. `re.search` searches for the content in your input that matches the
   pattern given.
2. `(\d\d)` means capture two digits, (hence this works only if you
   have two digits always for each category).
   Notice `\s` (space) and the colons are outside the parentheses, which means they are not captured.
3. Finally, we have 4 matches, so `.group(1, 2, 3, 4) returns a tuple
   of those four matches in order.